# reconstructing lost code (AddToArray)

Tags: delphi

I am missing a unit from some code that another developer worked on.

this is what I have been able to decipher from the rest of the units

I need a function called AddToArray.

I know it takes a TStringArray and String and returns a TStringArray

```
TStringArray = array of string;


function AddToArray (A: TStringArray; S: String): TStringArray;
begin
  // result:=
end;
```

I am not sure how the rest of it is completed.

any help would be appreciated.

thanx

Comment: I'd make it a procedure, instead. Anyhow, any simple implementation is likely to be non-optimal.

Comment: Use your imagination. What would you *expect* a function named `AddToArray` to do, when it receives a thing and an array of the same type as that thing?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this yourself? This looks like a "I have an assignment. Do my work for me" question with a made-up story to hide it. Please edit to show **your effort** to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious implementation would be:

```
function AddToArray(A: TStringArray; S: String): TStringArray;
begin
  Result := A;
  SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
  Result[high(Result)] := S;
end;
```

But if I were doing this I would use const parameters:

```
function AddToArray(const A: TStringArray; const S: String): TStringArray;
```

Well, if I were really doing this I'd use `TStringList`.